# Sub- or Superscript at Start of Formula

Tags: libreoffice-math

I am using Libreoffice Math and I can't figure out how to apply subscript without having a character in front of it. I want to display a carbon nucleus.

```
^{6}_{12}C
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured I can work around this issue this way:

```
""^{6}_{12}C
```

That does however left-align the sub- and superscript which makes it look a bit odd. Any suggestions as to how to right align it?

**EDIT:**
Figured it out:

```
C lsub{12}lsup{6}
```